# How to get webpack to inline css into the generated html file

Tags: sass, webpack

I'm trying to get webpack to inline some scss into the generated html file to use as my app-shell css.

The idea is to get webpack bundle any scss file ending in '-file.scss' into a css file and to inline any scss in files ending '-shell.scss'.

This way I would get my app-shell to style before react or anything else loads.

By inline I mean to put it in STYLE tags in the generated html file.

The css part of my webpack is:

```
    {
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: [paths.appSrc, paths.appNodeModules],
            // Disable autoprefixer in css-loader itself:
            // https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/281
            // We already have it thanks to postcss.
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?-autoprefixer!postcss')
        },
        {
            test: /-shell\.scss$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass'],
        },
        {
            test: /-file\.scss$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!sass'),
        },
```

I had thought that removing the ExtractTextPugin loader from "test: /-shell.scss$/" would do it but it doesn't put those styles into STYLE tags in the generated html build file.

I've adapted the Create React App setup from https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app